# How do I make turtles avoid patches in NETLOGO?

Tags: netlogo

My agents are boats moving on water, surrounding and at some places within that water are bits of land which need to be impossible to pass. I'm struggling to conceptualize how to tell an agent this information in netlogo.

I've assigned

```
patches-own
[DEPTH
PASSABLE?
]
```

with

```
ask patches with [DEPTH > 0] [set PASSABLE? FALSE]
```

**How do I tell a turtle to not cross over or occupy a patch with PASSABLE? = FALSE while engaging in an otherwise random walk search for**

```
patches in-radius VISION with [DEPTH = 10]
```

?

sorry for the lack of a reproducible example, but this is a more conceptual question than anything. I will rough out a simple example model if need be.

Answer (score 1):

When your agent is about to take a step forward, you can have them check if they can, then make them pick a new destination if they are going onto dry land

You can do this with [Patch-Ahead](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/patch-ahead.html) or In-Cone if you want. Use that to set the destination.

Somthing like:

```
to walk
 "pick destination"
     ifelse destination = water [fd 1] [walk]
end
```

To pick what the possible destination is, you use what the turtle's current heading is like this:

```
to pick-destination
  let destination patch-ahead 1
end
```

Comment: @ Andrew Yoak, thanks for the suggestion but I guess what I'm confused on is how to query the destination. The turtles are engaging in a random-ish walk (basically: right random-float 275 forward random-float 5) so I'm struggling with coming up with a way to have the turtle pick a spot via the random walk, then evaluate it like you're saying. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd use patch-head and a let command to temporarily define something as the "destination". I'll clarify that in the answer